# Datatable Parameters are Null , causing NumberFormatException:Null. Any Solution?

Tags: java, jquery, exception, datatables, numberformatexception

I have an action annotation which acts as a server side processing action for Jquery data-table. while getting the params of datatable, I m getting an exception. The class for getting params is:

```
package com.healthslate.reports.view.actions;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class DataTablesParamUtility {

public static JQueryDataTableParamModel getParam(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    if(request.getParameter("sEcho")!=null || request.getParameter("sEcho")!= "")
    {
        JQueryDataTableParamModel param = new JQueryDataTableParamModel();
        param.sEcho = request.getParameter("sEcho");
        param.sSearch = request.getParameter("sSearch");
        param.sColumns = request.getParameter("sColumns");
        param.iDisplayStart = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("iDisplayStart"));
        param.iDisplayLength= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("iDisplayLength") );
        param.iColumns = Integer.parseInt( request.getParameter("iColumns") );
        param.iSortingCols = Integer.parseInt( request.getParameter("iSortingCols") );
        param.iSortColumnIndex = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("iSortCol_0"));
        param.sSortDirection = request.getParameter("sSortDir_0");
        return param;
    }else
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am getting the exception at
     `param.iDisplayStart = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("iDisplayStart"));`

Exception is :

```
HTTP Status 500 - null

type Exception report

message null

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    com.healthslate.reports.view.actions.DataTablesParamUtility.getParam(DataTablesParamUtility.java:16)
    com.healthslate.reports.view.actions.pageVisitReportModifiedAction.serverSideSearch(pageVisitReportModifiedAction.java:78)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.interceptors.SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.intercept(SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.java:181)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    net.bull.javamelody.StrutsInterceptor.intercept(StrutsInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.35 logs.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NumberFormatException` occurs when you are trying to convert an illegal value to an `int` value. You need to check the value before you are trying to read them as `int` value

```
//Check the `iDisplayStart` parameter is not null 
if(request.getParameter("iDisplayStart")!=null)
//do the conversion if it is not null
param.iDisplayStart = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("iDisplayStart"))
```

Note: `iDisplayStart` parameter should contain a valid value, which can be parsed into an `int` value. otherwise, you will get `NumberFormatException`. You can also create an utility method which takes the input value, validate it and do the conversion and return the parsed `int` value. If any exception occurs in the utility method, it will return a `int` value denoting a failure or error

Answer (score 0):

There is something called as Exception handling. why have you not done that first.
Put your code inside a try - catch block and find th exact source of error.

A number format exception occurs when you try to parse a number there instead of a string.
Check the following code first and see what value you are getting if its a number or a string and please do exception handling properly otherwise even if your code works perfectly fine that would be your first review comment. atleast from me :)

```
 request.getParameter("iDisplayStart")
```

Comment: iDisplayStart is a string param of datatable.